# Marketplace access

Tags: android, google-play

Do app developers tag their apps before putting them in the market place, for search or categorization etc.? or is the search done based on the description?

Is it possible to create an app that displays/has access to apps from the market place and their description? This app should also allow apps download and installation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do app developers tag their apps before putting them in the market place, for search or categorization etc.? or is the search done based on the description?

Google Play does its search indexing based on what you write in your description and your title text. While adding tags in the format `Tags: abc, xyz` is not explicitly forbidden, there have been cases when apps using tags like that have been pulled as spam, and once in a while had the developer account suspended.

> Is it possible to create an app that displays/has access to apps from the market place and their description?

There are a few unofficial APIs to pull and display information from Google Play, like [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/) one.

However, if you're looking for an official implementation, at best you can launch particular pages in the Google Play app using the intents described [here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html).

> This app should also allow apps download and installation..

If you want to allow users to download and install apps through your app, you will need to ask developers to provide you with an apk of their app, which you store on a server and serve to your users. Additionally, you will not be able to do "silent" installs like Google Play does, and the users will have to explicitly give permission to install each app.